# SQL WHERE xx IN ('qq', 'ww'...) performance - more values, less time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am finally asking my first question (although I am a long-time stalker).

An SQL query caught my attention the other day at work. The problem is performance in `WHERE` clause, when comparing the index to possible values using `IN` operator.

```
SELECT   SUM (parts.quantity) AS quantity,
       concessions.concessionCode,
       concessions.description AS concessionDesc,
       parts.type,
       activities.activityCode,
       REPLACE (activities.activityCode, activities.lvl2 || '-', '') AS activityCodeDisplay,
       strings.activityDesc,
       strings.activityDesc2,
       strings.activityDesc3
FROM   tb_parts parts,
       tb_activities activities,
       tb_strings strings,
       tb_concessions concessions
WHERE       parts.activityCode = activities.activityCode
       AND parts.concessionCode = activities.concessionCode
       AND activities.concessionCode = concesions.concessionCode
       AND activities.concessionCode = strings.concessionCode
       AND activities.activityCode = strings.activityCode
       AND strings.language = 'ENG'
       --AND parts.concesionCode IN ('ZD', 'G9', 'TR', 'JS0')
       AND parts.concesionCode IN ('ZD', 'G9')
       AND parts.date >= TO_DATE ('01/01/2013 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       AND parts.date <= TO_DATE ('30/04/2013 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       AND parts.type IN ('U', 'M')
       AND parts.value = 'E'
GROUP BY   concesions.concessionCode,
       concesions.description,
       parts.type,
       activities.activityCode,
       REPLACE (activities.activityCode, activities.lvl2|| '-', ''),
       strings.activityDesc,
       strings.activityDesc2,
       strings.activityDesc3
ORDER BY   concesions.concessionCode;
```

The problem that I have is this - if the query is run like it is (with two values for the `IN`), it takes 30s. If it is run with four values (like it is in the commented line), the query takes 5s. I would expect that comparing the index against multiple values would take more time, but seems not to be the case. I have repeated the "test" several times during the day, and they are always more or less the same ( 30 +-1s, 5 +-1s).

Any insight into why this is behaving in such a manner would be more than appreciated!

P.S. I have translated the names of the tables/columns so sorry if there is any discrepancy.

P.P.S. I have rewritten this code with joins and it is much faster, but the reason behind this anomaly is still bothering me :)

**EDIT**: Finally at work! After some tinkering, I have been able to create execution plans for these two versions, and even for the third version of the query (with **both** 4 and 2 values in `where`, time is around 600 ms). Also, there were several questions about the data in the tables, so here are some information:

```
All the stats are analyzed the day that queries were executed

Table parts 
           total rows           - 3.2  M 
           matches for 2 values - 1.08 M (~34%)
           matches for 4 values - 1.30 M (~41%)
Table activities
           total rows           - 3866 
           matches for 2 values - 321    (~ 8%)
           matches for 4 values - 644    (~16%)
Table strings 
           total rows           - 7436
           matches for 2 values - 642    (~ 8%)
           matches for 4 values - 1288   (~17%)

Index in_parts
           codConcession
           username
           date
```

Because of that, I think that there is no major difference (apart from +2/3s) when using dynamic sampling (if i did it correctly, that is, with `/*+ dynamic_sampling(tb_parts 10) */` after the `SELECT` keyword)

For **two values**:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation                          | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                |     1 |   186 |   864   (1)| 00:00:11 | 
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                     |                |     1 |   186 |   864   (1)| 00:00:11 | 
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                    |                |     1 |   186 |   864   (1)| 00:00:11 | 
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | tb_parts       |     1 |    37 |   818   (1)| 00:00:10 | 
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                   |                |     1 |   186 |   862   (1)| 00:00:11 | 
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                |     1 |   149 |    44   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                |    34 |  2108 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   7 |        INLIST ITERATOR             |                |       |       |            |          | 
|   8 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| tb_concesions  |     2 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  9 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | pk_concession  |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|  10 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | tb_activities  |    17 |   595 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|* 11 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | pk_activity    |    17 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|  12 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | tb_strings     |     1 |    87 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|* 13 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | pk_string      |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|* 14 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | in_parts       |   454 |       |   648   (1)| 00:00:08 | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                   
---------------------------------------------------                                                   
   3 - filter("parts"."value"='E' 
              AND ("parts"."type"='M' OR "parts"."type"='U') 
              AND "parts"."activityCode"="activities"."activityCode")   

   9 - access("concessions"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='ZD')  

  11 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="concessions"."concessionCode")                           
       filter("activities"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='ZD')               

  13 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="strings"."concessionCode" 
              AND "activities"."activityCode"="strings"."activityCode" 
              AND "strings"."language"='ENG')    
       filter("strings"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='ZD')                     

  14 - access("parts"."concessionCode"="activities"."concessionCode" 
              AND "parts"."date">=TO_DATE('2013-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
              AND "parts"."date"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-04-30 23:59:59', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                   
       filter("parts"."date">=TO_DATE('2013-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                      'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')               
              AND ("parts"."concessionCode"='G9' 
                   OR "parts"."concessionCode"='ZD') 
              AND "parts"."date"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-04-30 23:59:59', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

For **four values**:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                |     1 |   186 |  7412   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                    |                |     1 |   186 |  7412   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                   |                |     1 |   186 |  7412   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                |     1 |   186 |  7410   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                     |                |    17 |  1683 |  7393   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                    |                |   136 |  8432 |    21   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| tb_concesions  |     4 |   108 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | pk_concession  |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | tb_activities  |   644 | 22540 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL            | tb_parts       |  4310 |   155K|  7372   (2)| 00:01:29 |
|  11 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | tb_strings     |     1 |    87 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | pk_string      |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   4 - access("parts"."activityCode"="activities"."activityCode" 
              AND "parts"."concessionCode"="activities"."concessionCode")                              

   5 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="concessions"."concessionCode")                         

   8 - access("concessions"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='ZD')           

   9 - filter("activities"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='ZD')             
  10 - filter("parts"."date">=TO_DATE(' 2013-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                      'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')             
              AND "parts"."value"='E' 
              AND ("parts"."type"='M' OR "parts"."type"='U') 
              AND ("parts"."concessionCode"='G9' 
                   OR "parts"."concessionCode"='JS0'
                   OR "parts"."concessionCode"='TR' 
                   OR "parts"."concessionCode"='ZD') 
              AND "parts"."date"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-04-30 23:59:59',    
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                            

  12 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="strings"."concessionCode" 
              AND "activities"."activityCode"="strings"."activityCode" 
              AND "strings"."language"='ENG')  
       filter("strings"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='ZD')
```

And finally **six values**:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                |     1 |   186 |  4525   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                    |                |     1 |   186 |  4525   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                   |                |     1 |   186 |  4525   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                |     1 |   186 |  4523   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                     |                |     9 |   891 |  4514   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                    |                |   136 |  8432 |    21   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       INLIST ITERATOR             |                |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| tb_concesions  |     4 |   108 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | pk_concession  |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | tb_activities  |   644 | 22540 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      INLIST ITERATOR              |                |       |       |            |          |
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | tb_parts       |  2155 | 79735 |  4493   (1)| 00:00:54 |
|* 12 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN           | in_parts       |  8620 |       |  1277   (1)| 00:00:16 |
|  13 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | tb_strings     |     1 |    87 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | pk_string      |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   4 - access("parts"."activityCode"="activities"."activityCode" 
   AND "parts"."concessionCode"="activities"."concessionCode")   

   5 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="concessions"."concessionCode")                         

   8 - access("concessions"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "concessions"."concessionCode"='ZD')           

   9 - filter("activities"."concessionCode"='G9' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "activities"."concessionCode"='ZD')             

  11 - filter("parts"."value"='E' 
              AND ("parts"."type"='M' OR "parts"."type"='U'))                   

  12 - access(("parts"."concessionCode"='G9' 
                 OR "parts"."concessionCode"='ZD') 
              AND "parts"."date">=TO_DATE(' 2013-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
              AND "parts"."date"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-04-30 23:59:59', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))            
       filter("parts"."date">=TO_DATE(' 2013-01-01 00:00:00', 
                                      'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')             
              AND "parts"."date"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-04-30 23:59:59', 
                                          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))        

  14 - access("activities"."concessionCode"="strings"."concessionCode" 
              AND "activities"."activityCode"="strings"."activityCode" 
              AND "strings"."language"='ENG')  
       filter("strings"."concessionCode"='G9'  
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='JS0' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='TR' 
              OR "strings"."concessionCode"='ZD')
```

Since this is my first meeting with execution plan, I can only guess at to what is the cause of the delay. 
Between 4 and 6 values I would guess that it is the change from FULL ACCESS to ACCESS BY INDEX. Also, when accessing the table the filter for four values (id 10) contains all four concession values; while for six values, the two concession values are in access part, and filter contains only date, type and value.

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: First thing to check is to compare query execution plans. More likely than not, with only two values the plan tries to start with some index on concessionCode which works badly for the specific values in question. With four, it goes some other way and ends up better.

Comment: Are stats up to date (particularly on the "parts" table)? What are the relative populations for the different values of parts.concesionCode? If you can post the two query plans - we should expect to see that they are different, possibly because of misleading stats.

Comment: If you run it with two values twice in rapid succession does the execution time go down?  If so, the slowness of the first query had nothing to do with the list.  It was simply compiling your query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, never thought to check (new to databases). Will post update as soon as I can check them (monday morning, to be precise)

Comment: @LordPeter same as the last two - will check the plans (until now, had no idea about them). Thx

Comment: @DanBracuk no, the time is always around 30s

Comment: +1 for the question being interesting and nicely formatted, although it must suck to work with the concesions table being misspelled like that.

Comment: It's often interesting to invoke optimiser dynamic sampling for a table with a lot of predicates placed on it -- PARTS in this case. You might like to look at whether it is being invoked already (the explain plan will tell you) and test a few different levels of sampling. With a query having a best execution speed of around five seconds, the overhead due to sampling is unlikely to be detrimental.

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks for the suggestion, i will look into it! As for the misspelling, that is completely my fault - the originals were in Spanish but thought it would be more polite to translate :)

Comment: @Archduke well i wish i could upvote it twice in that case

Comment: I suggest rewriting the query: I presume A) the Strings table provides translations for descriptions so it's basically a lookup table; and B) there are mandatory foreign keys from Parts to the other tables. If these presumptions hold, then I would use a Common Table Expression (`with` clause) to do the group by on the Parts table, including all of the restrictive (ie non-join) clauses in the where clause. Then join from this defined 'temporary result set' to the other tables to get the related information. This will allow you to remove the extra columns from the group by clause (which I hate).

Comment: This rewrite probably won't make your query faster but I think it will make it clearer. Although your case isn't bad, I have seen queries many times longer this with many more columns in the group by that are only there to satisfy the DBMS's wishes, but functionally they aren't needed -- they don't make the group by expression any more unique.

Comment: @Colin'tHart as soon as I saw the performance, I rewrote it (using joins, but with all the 'group by's though - I guess I could try to make it more readable), but what confuses me is (for me) illogical performance comparison.

Comment: SQL Server use an index if "selectivity" on column(s) are elevated. Probably on the parts.type column there are too few unique values for use index. Can you post the index on the relative columns ? The statistics and defragmentation on index are ok ? How much unique values there are on parts.type column ?

Comment: @Max This is Oracle (so not sure if the behavior is the same). Anyways, parts.type have only three or four distinct values, but it isn't part of any index that is used in any of the three plans.

Comment: I think the behaviour is the same, excuse me I think is the parts.type column with problems. In the concesionCode column how many disticnt values do you have ? Try to create an index with all columns of parts that you use in the where clausole, and/or try to change the order of the where clausole. See this http://www.dba-oracle.com/Oracle_tips_sql_predicate_order.htm

Comment: @max in the concessinoCode there are around 30-40 distinct values, but these two account for 30% of the parts. I would have thought that that's where the CBO is mistake. 
I will try to create an index with all the columns and see if the exec plan changes, but what really bothers me is what part of the existing DB data would cause the query to be executed this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the reason for such anomalies is that the query optimizer cannot accurately predict the cost. The only way to know the cost precisely would be to actually run the statement several times with different execution plans. Instead it uses statistics to *estimate* the cost, and sometimes the estimate is wrong.

When you compare the exection plans of "with two values" with "with four values" you can see the the latter yields higher cost and the plan is entirely different. The Optimizer had a choice between these two execution plans and must have thought the first is better with two values and the second is better with four values. However, in reality the second was better in both cases.

If you analyze such anomalies carefully you often end up with insights like a certain combination of values is overrepresented or underrespresented in your data. Using histograms in your statistics gives the optimizer more clues and it can handle "skewed data" better, but its forecast abilities will still be limited.

In practice, the solution is just what you did: rewrite the SQL until you get acceptable performance. Often "Hints" (in Oracle) can also give the optimizer more clues.

Comment: Nicely summed up, and thanks for the info about the hints (like I said, SQL newbie here :) )